# PDF form with Acrobat 2023: How can i force the order of signature fields being filled

Tags: pdf-form

Not sure if SO is the right platform for this question, but i assume/hope/think that it can be solved with javascript in the pdf file.

I am totally new to pdf-forms.

I have an pdf file (generated from a word file with adobe acrobat) that contains 3 parts, each part with some text fields and one signature field. I figured out how to lock the text fields in the same part after signing, but I need to

- force people to fill the text fields of the same part before they can sign the part. That probably could be solved in an event/action like onsign or so (to check if the required fields are not empty) but I did not find such an action in the signature-field-properties.

After one part is completed/signed the document is saved and sent to the next person. This person continues with the next open block and

- the person should only be able to fill/sign the next part (in this example part 2) so the form fields (including signature fields) of part 3 should be locked until part 2 is signed. Probably the same event/action and just check if the previous signature field is not empty.